# How to solve 2 differential equations with 2 variables (+time) in python

Tags: python, ode, solver

im quite new in python and i've been trying to solve a system of 2 simultaneous differential equations with 2 unkowns. Both variables `T,X` are a function of time, the derivative of T: `dT/dt` depends on both T and X while `dX_dt` depends only on X. My first thought was to create a function `fun(t,T,X)` which returns the values of `dT/dt` and `dX/dt` and use `solve_ivp` but it didn't work well. Can someone please tell me what is the proper way of solving such a system of ODEs? Thanks in advance. This is the script:

```
# Imports
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

# PARTICLE 

R =50*10**(-6) # Particle Radius (m)
rho = 575.4 # Initial Particle density  (kg/m^3)
mp0 = rho*4*math.pi*R**3/3 # Particle's initial mass
#t_c = 0.60 # C mass fraction in coal
t_ash = 0.245 #initial ash mass fraction in coal
mc0=mp0*(1-t_ash) # initial carbon mass fraction in coal
SSA =100000 # Coal Specific Surface Area (kg/m^2)
ep = 0.85 # Particle's emissivity
E= 153299 # Carbon combustion activation energy (J/mole)

# WALL AND AIR TEMPERATURES and pressure

Tw = 1000 # Wall temperature (K)
Ta = 300  # Air temperature (K)
p = 101325 # Aur pressure (Pa)


# OTHER CONSTANTS

sb = 5.670374419*10**(-8) # Stephan-Boltzman Constant ()
Rg = 8.31446261815324 # Gas constant (J/K mol)
Mc = 12.0107*10**(-3) # Carbon Molar Mass (kg/mole)
X_O2 = 0.20947 # Oxygen's Volumetric fraction in Air
Co2inf = X_O2*p/(Rg*Ta) # # Oxygen molar concentration in air (moles/m^3)

def fun(t,T, X):

    # Cp of carbon (J/kg K)
    Cpc = 3*Rg/Mc*math.exp(1200/T)*((math.exp(1200/T)-1)/(1200/T))**2
    # Cp of ash (J/kg K)
    Cpash = 754+0.586*(T-273.15)
    # Reaction Enthalpy of CO (J/mole -absolute value - temperature correction)
    DHco = 110.5*10**3 + 6.38*(T-298.15)
    # Reaction Enthalpy of CO2 (J/mole -absolute value - temperature correction)
    DHco2 = 393.5*10**3 + 13.1*(T-298.15)
    # CO/CO2 ratio
    CO_CO2 = 10**2.5*math.exp(-25000/(Rg*T))
    # Particle-Air boundary layer mean temperature
    Tm = (T+Ta)/2
    # Air thermal conductivity (W/m K -was used for gas with different O2 content!!!!)
    lamda = 0.0207*(Tm/273.15)**2*(1+113.15/273.15)/(1+113.15/Tm)
    # Convection coefficient (W/m^2 K - Nusselt=2)
    h = lamda/R
    # Effective diffusivity of oxygen within the particle, (m^2/s)
    Do2 = 1.78*10**(-5)*(Tm/273.15)**1.75
    # Mass transfer coefficient of oxygen (m/s - Sherwood=2)
    kd = Do2/R
    # Kinetic constant (m/s)
    ks = 1050*math.exp(-153200/(Rg*T))
    # L parameter
    L = (CO_CO2+1)/(CO_CO2/2+1)
    # Oxygen Flux
    FluxO2 = Co2inf/(3*L/(ks*rho*4*math.pi*R**3*SSA)+1/(kd*4*math.pi*R**2))

    # HEAT BALANCE EQUATION
    dT_dt= (4*math.pi*R**2*ep*sb*(Tw**4-T**4) +  4*math.pi*R**2*h*(Ta-T) + (CO_CO2*DHco+DHco2)*FluxO2/(1+CO_CO2/2))/(mc0*(1-X)*Cpc+mp0*t_ash*Cpash)

    # Combustion Reaction
    dX_dt= Co2inf*Mc*ks*SSA*(1-X)

    return [dT_dt, dX_dt]

Init_cond=[300,0]

OutputTimes = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
ans = solve_ivp(fun, (0, 20), Init_cond, method='RK45', t_eval=OutputTimes)
```

Answer (score 1):

The same way that your return value, the derivative of the state, is a tuple (or conceptually a vector), the ODE function also has to accept the state as a tuple/vector of the same dimension. The solver is based on implementing systems of ODE via vector-valued vector functions.

```
def fun(t,u):
    T, X = u;
    # etc.
```

With this change your program should run or at least give more interesting errors.

---

You might want to try out if the `method="Radau"` results in a faster integration with much less internal steps, as it is often the case.

Comment: A _small_ suggestion.  According to the documentation, the ODE function is passed an `ndarray` for the second input parameter and is required to return something `array_like`.  The tuple terminology might be confusing as a tuple is not passed in, although you might be able to return one.  Also, be careful that this method only works when not using `vectorized=True`, but it isn't important for this particular problem.

Comment: @MatthewFlamm : There is no problem in this place using the vectorized variant resp. solve_bvp which is always vectorized. The argument is an array containing the T and X sequences for the sample points, so that tuple assignment works as intended. You only need to pay attention if you want to reshape the state vector in some matrix valued state.